# get hidden input value with looping in a table

Tags: jquery

I tried a lot and searched a lot to find a solution for my question, but I lost. every time I found a partial solution not all I need as one piece. so my question is I have a table holding data on it as shown , I hold the id in the first column in a hidden input . I want to get this Id and the other values while looping in the table . I found a solution to get the id only or the other values only . what I need to loop in the table to get the whole data with each other.

I hold the id in the first column with id to the input (#id)

```
if (response.length > 0) {

             
                $('#catprop').html('');

                table += '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id=_catprop>';
                table += '<thead class="thead-dark">';
                table += '<tr><th>Property</th><th>Value</th></tr>';
                table += '</thead>';
                table += '<tbody>';

                for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                    table += '<tr>';
                    table += '<td><input type="hidden" id="id" value="' + response[i].id + '" asp-for="' + response[i].id + '">' + response[i].title + '</td>';
                    table += '<td><input type="text" asp-for="' + response[i].value + '"/></td>';
                    table += '</tr>';
                }
                table += '</tbody></table>';
                $('#catprop').append(table);

            }
            else {
                $('#catprop').empty();
                table = '<p> No Property For Selected Category !! </p>';
                $('#catprop').append(table);
            }
```

the function to get the value of the table

```
           $('#btnsave').on("click", function () {
           var table = document.getElementById("_catprop").rows;

           for (let i = 1; i < table.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < table[i].cells.length; j++) {
                //how to loop to get the id inside the hidden input + the innerText of html
                //of the other values with each other
            }
        }
```

Comment: First, IDs in HTML must be Unique and I see you have `id` set for each row. This will cause unexpected results.

Comment: Where is `response` defined? Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

As @Twisty pointed out in his comment, the multiple `id`s will prevent your code from working properly. In fact there is no need to use hidden inputs in the first place. You could use `data-id` attributes instead on each `<tr>` to hold the `response[i].id` information like:

```
..
...
table += `<tr data-id="${response[i].id}">
  <td>${response[i].title}</td>
  <td>${response[i].value}</td></tr>`;
...
..
.
```

The data collection routine would then be:

```
const res=document.getElementById("_catprop").rows
  .reduce((a,r)=>{
    a[r.dataset.id]=[...r.cells].map(c=>c.textContent);
    return a;
  }, {});
```

**UPDATE**

OK, after putting everything into a snippet I arrived at this slightly different solution. Here I assemble the table-HTML and the cell contents array `tds` at the same time:

```js
var tds = [];
$.getJSON("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=7")
  .then(response => {
    $('#catprop').html(
      response.length ?
      `<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="_catprop">
     <thead class="thead-dark"><tr><th>Property</th><th>Value</th></tr></thead>
     <tbody>${response.map(r =>{let val=r.body.slice(0,20);
     tds.push([r.id,r.title,val]);
     return `<tr id="${r.id}"><td>${r.id}: ${r.title}</td>
     <td><input type="text" asp-for="${val}" 
     value="${val}"/></td></tr>`}).join("\n")}</tbody></table>` :
      '<p> No Property For Selected Category !! </p>'
    )
   console.log(tds)
   $("button").click(function(){
  console.log($("#_catprop tbody tr").map((_,t)=>t.id).toArray());
})
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>loop over table</button>
<div id="catprop"></div>
```

Instead of an `if then else` construct I used the ternary operator

```
 response.length ? <take this> : <else take that>
```

The datasource `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts` is a pulic JSON service for testing. Instead of `value` there is ony a `body` attribute with every object. From this property I slice off the first 20 characters.

Comment: apologize for my ignorance .. your solution is complex for me , can you provide it with a simplest way .. and last thing i want to store each td data ( id , title , value ) in a variable to send it the controller

Comment: all what I need to do is to show the table with it's data (id, title, value ) => value is a text box which i will add in it the value of the selected row . after that I want to take the add value with it's title and id to put them in viewmodel and send it back to the controller to save it to the database . your last update is nice , but my problem was in i cannot take the selected id from the table when looping in the table .

Comment: I just changed the `data-id` attributes to `id`. As long as these ids are unique you should be now be able to identify and select individual `<tr>`s.

Comment: still I cannot get the id from the table while looping in it . it gives me undefined .. this only my problem .

Comment: Just added a button to loop over the `<tr>`s. It works.